# Flex-box: not aligning items as expected

Tags: css, flexbox

I have been creating a site and noticed that the flex-box justify-content property is having no effect. This is set to center but the flexbox items appear to align at the start of the container's horizontal axis. Not too sure why this is the case. I have set out both the css and HTML that I have used. Any suggestions would be very helpful!

```css
/*General settings*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,400;1,300&display=swap');
* {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}


/*nav settings*/

.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #0077c2;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2vw 0;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.nav-container ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 10vw;
}

.nav-container li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1vw;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 2vw;
  color: #fff;
}

.logo :hover {
  border: 3px #ff8000 solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  text-decoration: 3px underline #ff8000;
}


/*img section*/

.img-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 5vw;
  border: 2px #ff8000 solid;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 5vh auto;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.img-container img {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-container p {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="nav-container">

    <div class="logo">
      <h1>Development<br>One</h1>
    </div>

    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Apple Development</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Android development</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</header>

<section class="img-container">

  <div>
    <h2>Section One Title</h2>
    <img src="img/androiddevelopers.png" alt="app-development">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt repellendus nemo eveniet sint. Consectetur error totam nulla ex alias dolorum minus nostrum. Ex est suscipit dolor dolores repellendus! Architecto, ducimus?</p>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <h2>Section two Title</h2>
    <img src="img/androiddevelopers.png" alt="app-development">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt repellendus nemo eveniet sint. Consectetur error totam nulla ex alias dolorum minus nostrum. Ex est suscipit dolor dolores repellendus! Architecto, ducimus?</p>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <h2>Section three Title</h2>
    <img src="img/androiddevelopers.png" alt="app-development">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt repellendus nemo eveniet sint. Consectetur error totam nulla ex alias dolorum minus nostrum. Ex est suscipit dolor dolores repellendus! Architecto, ducimus?</p>
  </div>
  
</section>
```

Comment: What are you trying to center exactly ? there are multiply flex-boxes in your sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`justify-content: center` is working for the `.nav-container`. You just didn't recognize because the three `div`s filled out the whole space.

**Working example:** (*with smaller width for demonstration*)

```css
/*General settings*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,400;1,300&display=swap');
* {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}


/*nav settings*/

.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #0077c2;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2vw 0;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.nav-container ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 10vw;
}

.nav-container li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1vw;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 2vw;
  color: #fff;
}

.logo :hover {
  border: 3px #ff8000 solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  text-decoration: 3px underline #ff8000;
}


/*img section*/

.img-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 5vw;
  border: 2px #ff8000 solid;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 5vh auto;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.img-container div {
  width: 20%;
}

.img-container img {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-container p {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="nav-container">

    <div class="logo">
      <h1>Development<br>One</h1>
    </div>

    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Apple Development</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Android development</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</header>

<section class="img-container">

  <div>
    <h2>Section One Title</h2>
    <img src="img/androiddevelopers.png" alt="app-development">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt repellendus nemo eveniet sint. Consectetur error totam nulla ex alias dolorum minus nostrum. Ex est suscipit dolor dolores repellendus! Architecto, ducimus?</p>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <h2>Section two Title</h2>
    <img src="img/androiddevelopers.png" alt="app-development">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt repellendus nemo eveniet sint. Consectetur error totam nulla ex alias dolorum minus nostrum. Ex est suscipit dolor dolores repellendus! Architecto, ducimus?</p>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <h2>Section three Title</h2>
    <img src="img/androiddevelopers.png" alt="app-development">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt repellendus nemo eveniet sint. Consectetur error totam nulla ex alias dolorum minus nostrum. Ex est suscipit dolor dolores repellendus! Architecto, ducimus?</p>
  </div>
  
</section>
```